# How to only export the folder "Documents" under /home/ <users>?

Tags: nfs

I hope someone can help with the following problem:

```
system: CentOS 7
Service: NFS-server
```

I need to only export the folder `"/home/%USER%/Documents"` for all the users. How can I do to configure my `/etc/exports` file.

I did try to use regex syntax in /etc/exports such as

```
/home/*/Documents    *(rw,sysc,no_roo_squash)
/home/\*/Documents    *(rw,sysc,no_roo_squash)
```

but they do not work.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is off-topic here (it's not a programming question). I suggest looking at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [unix.se].

Comment: I don't think this is programming question,  I want to find out that NFS does support regex on share location or it is doesn't. If it does support, what is the syntax.

Comment: This is _not_ a programming question on a site that is _only_ for them. Please see the site [tour]. I linked 2 other StackExchange sites where this question would be appropriate - here it will not be answered.

Comment: Sorry if it comes off as unwelcoming, but there is a specific purpose to StackOverflow outlined in that tour I linked; there are other StackExchange sites for other topics, and what you ask is more appropriate there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information.